# Comment out all lines that do not start with #

Tags: bash, shell, sed

The main goal of this activity is to get all the lines that are not commented at the beginning of each line and then comment them. I need both, first know them and then change them.

I have the below `testfile`:

```
line1
#comment1
#comment2
wrongcomment#
line2
#comment3
## double comment with space
#
#
 # empty space and comment
[ lineinBrackets ]
( lineinBrackets2 )
LinewithValue = 2
```

On my current task first I'm trying to get the lines that are not commented, doing a simple grep:

```
grep -vi '^#' testfile
```

that gives me the expected output:

```
line1
wrongcomment#
line2
 # empty space and comment
[ lineinBrackets ]
( lineinBrackets2 )
LinewithValue = 2
```

Now I'm trying to apply sed to add a `#` at the beginning of the line, but is not working[one line shell execution as example, this should be on a script]:

NOTE: I can't just add a # to each line every time I run the script. That's why I try to only add to where it doesn't start with the # and match the pattern I get from the grep. –

```
for i in $(grep -vi '^#' testfile); do sed -e '/<pattern>/ s/^#*/#/g' -i testfile;done
```

And is does nothing.

Wanting to find the error try this
if I try the same with an `echo` it apply line breaks in each space.

```
for i in $(grep -vi '^#' testfile); do echo $i;done
```

Gives:

```
line1
wrongcomment#
line2
#
empty
space
[
lineinBrackets
]
(
lineinBrackets2
)
LinewithValue
=
2
```

That is not what I expected.

I have tested each part alone and it works, but when I try to integrate them it doesn't work.

```
for i in $(grep -vi '^#' testfile); do sed -e '/$i/ s/^#*/#/g' -i testfile;done
```

**As requested the final output we need is:**
*Which lines have to be edited:*

```
line1
wrongcomment#
line2
 # empty space and comment
[ lineinBrackets ]
( lineinBrackets2 )
LinewithValue = 2
```

*And the edition of the same on the file:*

```
#line1
#comment1
#comment2
#wrongcomment#
#line2
#comment3
## double comment with space
#
#
# # empty space and comment
#[ lineinBrackets ]
#( lineinBrackets2 )
#LinewithValue = 2
```

I need to be able to handle both results.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pattern that matches lines that start with `#`. Then negate the condition with `!` and substitute `#` at the beginning.

```
sed -i '/^#/!s/^/#/' testfile
```

Comment: If already indented commented lines should be excluded too, use `sed -i '/^\s*#/!s/^/#/' file`

Comment: @potong But the "expected output" when just viewing the non-commented lines with `grep` includes indented comments.

Comment: That's why I said "if".

Comment: Correct. If they want something different from what they said they want, the answer is different.

Answer (score 2):

To edit a file, use a file editor.

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/^#/s/^/#' 'w' | ed testfile
```

`ed` opens the named file and applies command read from standard input to it.

The `s` command substitutes a `#` for the empty string at the start of each line. `v/^#/` only applies the following `s` command to lines that *don't* begin with a `#`. The `w` command writes all pending changes to the file.

When everything has been read from standard input, the editor exits.

You can write the same command using a here document:

```
ed testfile <<EOF
v/^#/s/^/#
w
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/^#?/#/' file
#line1
#comment1
#comment2
#wrongcomment#
#line2
#comment3
## double comment with space
#
#
# # empty space and comment
#[ lineinBrackets ]
#( lineinBrackets2 )
#LinewithValue = 2
```

I don't know why you'd need this but in your question you say you do so - here's how to display the lines that will be changed by the above:

```
$ grep -v '^#' file
line1
wrongcomment#
line2
 # empty space and comment
[ lineinBrackets ]
( lineinBrackets2 )
LinewithValue = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, add a `#` to the beginning of lines that do not start with a `#`:

```
awk '{print (/^#/ ? "" : "#") $0}' testfile
```

or

```
awk '{print !/^#/ ? "#"$0 : $0}' testfile
```

Comment: Updated answer to include @EdMorton's suggestion that is more readable and a bit more DRY.

Answer (score 0):

a very unseemly way to do it in `awk` :

> ```
> gawk   '$_ = __$NF' FS=^# __=#
> nawk  '$-_ = __$NF' FS=^# __=#
> mawk '$!NF = __$NF' FS=^# __=#
> ```

```
#line1
#comment1
#comment2
#wrongcomment#
#line2
#comment3
## double comment with space
#
#
# # empty space and comment
#[ lineinBrackets ]
#( lineinBrackets2 )
#LinewithValue = 2
```